# AttributeError: Label instance has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, tkinter

The goal of my code is to have sliders that as their number is changed insert text into a text box. However, I can't seem to find what is causing the "AttributeError: Label instance has no attribute 'insert'" error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter 
from Tkinter import *
root = Tkinter.Tk() #The root/base

def math(): #This is the command that does the math
    text.insert(Tkinter.END, base +height + radius)
    text.see(Tkinter.END)

text = Text(root, width=10, height=20, background='#FFFFFF')
text.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=2)

text = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Change slider\nTo Desired\nValue')
text.grid(row=0, column=1)
####
#Variables
####
base = Tkinter.IntVar()
base.set(0)
height = Tkinter.IntVar()
height.set(0)
radius = Tkinter.IntVar()
radius.set(0)
####
#Sliders
####

base_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, variable=base, 
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,   
                       label='Base', command=math)
base_slider.grid(row=1, column=1)

height_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, variable=height, 
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,   
                       label='Height', command=math)
height_slider.grid(row=2, column=1)

radius_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, variable=radius, 
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,   
                       label='Radius', command=math)
radius_slider.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have two same named variables. The second one will overwrite the first and it will be lost. You will need to give one of them a different name and amend your code to use that name where applicable. Also `text.insert(Tkinter.END, base +height + radius)` => `text.insert(Tkinter.END, base.get() + height.get() + radius.get())`

Comment: Thanks Paul, but now that I have fixed the above problem I get the error "TypeError: math() takes no arguments (1 given)"

Comment: Give `math` a single parameter. Call it what you like, you aren't using it. Tkinter is calling it with one argument, so it needs to have one parameter, even if you ignore it. Also move `math down below the instantiation of `text`.

Comment: Those variables are all `IntVar`s so they should have get. Watch out that you are not reassigning those variables to something else.

Comment: The code works now, I accidentally gave it a variable that was already being used. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables with the same name.

Both your `Label` and `Text` widgets are called `text`. As the label is the second object to be assigned that is what is associated with the variable `text` from then onwards.

You think you are insert on a `Text` widget but it's a `Label`, which lacks that method.

To fix it give the widgets different names.

Fixed up code, the comments on the question give more info.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter 
from Tkinter import *
root = Tkinter.Tk() #The root/base

text = Text(root, width=10, height=20, background='#FFFFFF')
text.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=2)

label = Tkinter.Label(root, text='Change slider\nTo Desired\nValue')
label.grid(row=0, column=1)

def math(arg): #This is the command that does the math
    text.insert(Tkinter.END, base.get() +height.get() + radius.get())
    text.see(Tkinter.END)

####
#Variables
####
base = Tkinter.IntVar()
base.set(0)
height = Tkinter.IntVar()
height.set(0)
radius = Tkinter.IntVar()
radius.set(0)
####
#Sliders
####

base_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, variable=base,
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                       label='Base', command=math)
base_slider.grid(row=1, column=1)

height_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, variable=height,
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,   
                       label='Height', command=math)
height_slider.grid(row=2, column=1)

radius_slider = Tkinter.Scale(root, from_=0, to=500, variable=radius,
                       orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL,
                       label='Radius', command=math)
radius_slider.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```